# Adapting Foundation navigation CSS

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, nav

I'm trying to adapt as best I can ZURB's Foundation to the CMS we use. It's a CMS that will be alien to all but about 9 people; it's called Sitekit (sitekit.net) and it's not the most flexible of beasts.

As is the case with other CMSes, Sitekit creates its own navigation structure. It's relatively simple, in this case. An example of a simple one element nav with child/dropdown elements:

```
    <div id="menu"><ul id="level2"><li><span class="navfirst"><a class="level1" accesskey="A" title="fitness - AccessKey: A" href="/test-2.htm">fitness</a></span></li>
<li><a class="level1" accesskey="B" title="skate - AccessKey: B" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/skate/">skate</a></li>
<li><a class="level1" accesskey="C" title="play - AccessKey: C" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/play/">play</a></li>
<li><a class="level1" accesskey="E" title="cafe - AccessKey: E" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/food-and-drink/">cafe</a></li>
<li><a class="level1" accesskey="F" title="climb - AccessKey: F" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/schools.htm">climb</a></li>
<li><span class="navlast"><a class="level1x" accesskey="G" title="parties - AccessKey: G" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/parties.htm">parties</a></span>
<ul><li><a title="Ashton" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/new_page.htm">Ashton</a></li></ul></li></ul></div>
```

Obviously this is massively different to the way Foundation requires that you style your code to work with its navigational structure.

The point where it starts to mess up is where my CMS handles child elements in nav. It simply opens up a `<ul><li>` inside the parent element, whereas Foundation demands more specificity. I cannot customise the tags generated by my CMS.

My question is, what's the easiest way to make the navigation baked into my CMS, work within Foundation's Top Bar navigation structure?

Comment: Why can't you customize tags generated by your CMS? What CMS are you using? It doesn't use templates or you can't customize it in any way...? If you want to redesign your page to use Foundation, you will ***have to*** change the code, it can't be done only by change of CSS.

Comment: Hey A. You have no idea how inflexible this CMS is. Worse, I'm kinda hamstrung from changing it. Anyway, that's politics.

It works ok with parent pages, but not dropdowns/child pages. What I'm thinking of doing is working with single level nav automatically generated, then manually adding in the only nav element with child pages. That *should* work but it's not perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this piece of javascript to adapt your menus ...

It has some sugar options:

- **title**: a string that will appear on the left side of the menu
- **url**: a url for the title link
- **iconTitle**: a string that will appear on the right side of the menu
- **icon**: a boolean (true or false) to enable the right menu icon on mobile

**Usage eg.:**

```
formatNavBar($('#menu'), {title: 'Topnav', icon: false, true: 'http://www.howebridge.org'});
```

**The code:**

```js
var formatNavBar = function (menu, opts) {  
  $('span', menu).each(function () {
    var span = $(this);
    span.parent().prepend(span.children());
  });
  $('span', menu).remove();
  menu.addClass('top-bar').attr({
    'data-topbar': '',
    'role': 'navigation'
  });
  var section = $('<section>').addClass('top-bar-section');
  if ($('.title-area', menu).length === 0) {
    var titleUl = $('<ul>').addClass('title-area');
    var titleLi =  $('<li>').addClass('name');
    var title = $('<h1>');
    var titleLink = $('<a href="'+(opts.url || '#')+'">'+(opts.title || 'Menu')+'</a>');    
    titleUl.append(titleLi);
    titleLi.append(title);
    title.append(titleLink);    
    var mobile = $('<li>').addClass('toggle-topbar' + (opts.icon ? ' menu-icon' : ''))
    .html('<a href="#"><span>'+(opts.iconTitle || '')+'</span></a>');
    if (opts.icon) {
      $(document.body).on('click', '.toggle-topbar.menu-icon a', function() {
        menu.toggleClass('expanded');
      });
    }
    titleUl.append(mobile);            
    menu.prepend(titleUl);
  }
  section.append(menu.children());
  menu.append(section);
  $('ul', menu).addClass('left');
  $('li > ul', menu).each(function () {
    $(this).addClass('dropdown').parent().addClass('has-dropdown');
  });
  $(document).foundation('topbar', 'reflow');
};

formatNavBar($('#menu'), {title: 'Topnav', icon: true, url: 'http://www.howebridge.org'});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/css/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul id="level2">
        <li><span class="navfirst"><a class="level1" accesskey="A" title="fitness - AccessKey: A" href="/test-2.htm">fitness</a></span></li>
        <li><a class="level1" accesskey="B" title="skate - AccessKey: B" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/skate/">skate</a></li>
        <li><a class="level1" accesskey="C" title="play - AccessKey: C" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/play/">play</a></li>
        <li><a class="level1" accesskey="E" title="cafe - AccessKey: E" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/food-and-drink/">cafe</a></li>
        <li><a class="level1" accesskey="F" title="climb - AccessKey: F" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/schools.htm">climb</a></li>
        <li><span class="navlast"><a class="level1x" accesskey="G" title="parties - AccessKey: G" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/parties.htm">parties</a></span>
          <ul>
            <li><a title="Ashton" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/new_page.htm">Ashton</a></li>
            <li><a title="Ashton2" href="/leisure-centres-2016/howe-bridge/new_page2.htm">Ashton2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a JSbin if you wanna tweak something http://jsbin.com/nelafe/3

Comment: No way! Are you a REAL wizard? That's unbelievable. How do people know this stuff? I have given you the equivalent of gold on Reddit.

Comment: Hey Rafael. Sorry to be a nuisance, but how do I amend the JS you created above to invoke menu functionality with smaller screen sizes? I followed your advice changing the Usage to

'formatNavBar($('#menu'), {title: 'Topnav', icon: true});'

And the menu icon appears, but it's not functional. You click it, and nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you SO much. Once I reboot the server I'll be giving this a shot. It looks bulletproof, though. You're an absolute genius, Rafael!

Comment: Rafael - question: the HTML generated in the nav to display the name of this website should return users to the home page. But instead it generates a # rather than the URL (which in this case should be howebridge.org).

How do I append this URL to appear in the code generated on the website below?

<ul class="title-area left"><li class="name"><h1><a href="#" style="width: 100%; padding-right: 0px;">Howe Bridge Leisure Centre</a></h1></li><li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li></ul>

Comment: I just added an extra option for the url ... this made the code way better since it no longer uses a "hack" to adjust the icon click.

Comment: Raf - message me. I'll buy you something off your Amazon Wish List. D